# yii framework render structure

Tags: php, yii

i have a question about render a view Steps in yii framework, when i call this line:

```
$this->render('test',array('model'=>$model));
```

in a column2 layout form first off all framework run **layout->main.php** and then it runs **layout->column2.php** and next it runs my view **site->test.php** 
my question is that how framework do this steps and how framework understand when i use this command:

```
<?php echo $content;?>
```

which `$content` is proper conten to use now ?

 tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this  is a customized column2 layout . I use this for sample an explain the step

```
 <?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div class="span-19">
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div>
<div class="span-5 last">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <?php
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
            'title'=>'Operations',
        ));
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
        ));
        $this->endWidget();
    ?>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

then the code is executed sequntially. The part

```
 <?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
```

show the main layout

and in the main.php  layout main.php the line

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

echoes the content of the column1.php or column2.php, so they do not replace part of the code in main.php, their content is just echoed inside main.php.

the rendering of the view recalled by the render in controller is done here

```
<div class="span-19">
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div>
```

this part manage the secondo column and end the content

```
<div class="span-5 last">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <?php
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
            'title'=>'Operations',
        ));
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
        ));
        $this->endWidget();
    ?>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

I hope this is useful

the render from controller  initialize  $content show in layout2 $content .. this is rendered in one other $content rendered in main.php $content.

Then main.php $content contain the content result of layout2 and layout2 contian the content resul form your view

Comment: hi tnx for ur answer i want to know where $content is 
Initialized on every step i mean in example when i want to echo $a as 1  i set  $a=1 and then i use echo $1, where framework set value for $content?